# npm package.json bin chmod error

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have created an npm package and I am trying to install it from a git repository. Everything works fine when I run `npm install /path/to/package/ --no-bin-links`, but I have my package.json set up to link the main JS file into `bin`. When I try to install the package normally, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! path /staging/webshares/proj-test/node_modules/jkvc-project/index.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, chmod '/staging/webshares/proj-test/node_modules/jkvc-project/index.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

The `index.js` file definitely exists, and everything in my `package.json` looks normal:

```
{
  "name": "jkvc-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "JKD Project Build Tool",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
    "optimist": "~0.6.0",
    "prompt": "~0.2.12",
    "q": "~1.0.0",
    "request": "~2.33.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "./scss"
  ],
  "bin": "./index.js"
}
```

I have tried `npm cache clean`, but it didn't help. I also have a blank `.npmignore` file in the directory.

Does anyone know what it causing this `chmod` error, and how to fix it?

This is the folder structure of my package:

```
scss
.gitignore
.npmignore
index.js
package.json
```

Comment: The problem seems to be happening before the chmod. `npm` expects `index.js` to exist in `/staging/webshares/proj-test/node_modules/jkvc-project/`, but it can't find it there. Any other errors during the install?

Comment: maybe root owns it due to a previous `sudo npm install`?

Comment: @Plato I did a `rm -rf node_modules` before trying the command again

Comment: @robertklep nope... that's all the errors. `index.js` is in the top level of my package, and I'm trying to have that symlinked into `bin`. Is my path to the file for the `bin` key incorrect?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I can recreate the problem if `index.js` is being ignored by `.gitignore`, but an empty `.npmignore` fixes it, so it's weird that that won't work for you...

Comment: my `.gitignore` is ignoring `node_modules/` but `.npmignore` is an empty file

Comment: @robertklep The problem was the `files` key in package.json. I thought `files` would add folders to the install, but if you use `files` it ONLY includes those items.